# Jaspersoft Reports, how to check if a file exists or not in IF-ELSE clause?

Tags: jasper-reports

For a Jaspersoft Report I have an HTML file(very simple string content, no HTML marks) which I load into a Text Field, the loading path is dynamic, so it depends on a given parameter. Loading the HTML file works fine, I used this code:

```
new String(net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInstance($P{JASPER_REPORTS_CONTEXT}).getBytesFromLocation("repo:/home/res/html/file_" + $P{PARAM_HTML} + ".html"), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

If i try it with a file who doesnt exists, i get the following error message:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: new String(net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInstance($P{JASPER_REPORTS_CONTEXT}).getBytesFromLocation("repo:/home/res/html/file_" + $P{PARAM_HTML} + ".html"), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.fillReport(ReportController.java:551)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.access$18(ReportController.java:526)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController$1.run(ReportController.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: new String(net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInstance($P{JASPER_REPORTS_CONTEXT}).getBytesFromLocation("repo:/home/res/html/file_" + $P{PARAM_HTML} + ".html"), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.handleEvaluationException(JREvaluator.java:294)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:328)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:673)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:641)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1173)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:555)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:540)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:548)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:325)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:258)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:621)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at: repo:/home/res/html/file_12.html.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getBytesFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:215)
    at Blank_A4_1636094714772_424965.evaluate(Blank_A4_1636094714772_424965:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:313)
    ... 13 more
```

The Problem is, that it is not clear if the file exists or not, so I use a IF-ELSE clause to check if the HTML file exists or not. If the file exists, the content should be loaded into the Text Field, if not, a default HTML file should be used instead. What I've tried so far are the following conditions in the Text Field expression.

```
(new File("repo:/home/res/html/file_" + $P{PARAM_HTML} + ".html").isFile()) ? "LOAD FILE" : "LOAD DEFAULT FILE"
```

```
(new File("repo:/home/res/html/file_" + $P{PARAM_HTML} + ".html").exists()) ? "LOAD FILE" : "LOAD DEFAULT FILE"
```

I also tried the same conditions to use in a variable, and use the variable in the Text Field. Always it uses the ELSE condition, even if the file exists or not.

I am not sure where my mistake is, or what I did wrong.

Comment: What happens to `getBytesFromLocation` when the file doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i forgot to add the error message :( . Now I've editet the original post with it...

Comment: I think class `File` is unable to understand this type of location "repo:/home...".
Create a separate java program with only this `File f = new File("repo:/home/res/html/file_" + $P{PARAM_HTML} + ".html")`. Replace the parameter with a value you know exists. Then print the location the `File` is pointing to with `getAbsolutePath` or other methods.

Comment: If I understand it right, it is not so easy to create a separate java programm, my understanding is that this is to do on the server and compile the code there? Am I right? And i fear that is not possibly for me, because I only have access to the Report design and not to the server.

Comment: I don't know what and where "repo:/home/res" is. I'm assuming it's local.

Comment: It's a path in the repository, from the server. I use the same path with other subfolders for loading images, and that works fine. So I think the path syntax should be correct!?